# Build JSON REST api/webservices in vs2010 or vs2012 that will consumed by ajax clients in mobile devices

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2010, rest, visual-studio-2012

I have an Existing Web application builded two years ago with VS2010  ASP.NET Web Forms, C# and SQL SERVER 2008 .Now i want to build mobile version and install it in mobile devices. I want to develop it using JQuery Ajax, Jquery Mobile and Apache Cordova. My simple question is how can build  serialize from database json REST api/webservices in vs2010 or vs2012 that will consumed by ajax clients in mobile devices  ???

Thanks to all

Comment: WebAPI, although Google could have told you as much: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: Can i install web api in vs 2010 ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you for WebAPI. because of following reasons.

If we need a Web Service and don’t need SOAP, then ASP.Net Web API is best choice.
It is Used to build simple, non-SOAP-based HTTP Services on top of existing WCF message pipeline.
It doesn't have tedious and extensive configuration like WCF REST service.
Simple service creation with Web API. With WCF REST Services, service creation is difficult.
It is only based on HTTP and easy to define, expose and consume in a REST-ful way.
It is light weight architecture and good for devices which have limited bandwidth like smart phones.
It is open source.

Tutorial is here.
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-603

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a lot of coding, and use SlashDB. http://www.slashdb.com/how-it-works/

It will automatically make a web API for an existing database. Your case is very typical because many websites use server-side templates to make dynamic HTML, which of course does not work well if you need a native app or a highly responsive HTML5 mobile page.

Disclosure: I am the founder and CEO of the company behind SlashDB, but you don't have to take my word it - just try it.